# strike thru text doesn't save

Tags: java, android, paint

I'm in the process of making a grocery list app and I wrote the code to where when I click an item, it'll mark it off.

This is my code for that section:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                TextView text = (TextView) view;
                if (!text.getPaint().isStrikeThruText()) {
                    text.setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags() |  Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                }else{
                    text.setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
                }


            }
        });
        }
```

It works exactly like i want but when I add another item after an item is marked off, all of the items that are marked off, the marks disappear.

When I add an item, it's like it resets. it doesn't delete any of my items, just the strike_thru part of it. any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your ListView's Adapter contains a method called `getView`, which is called when a list view item needs to be displayed in an actual View. The Views in your ListView will be discarded if you scroll too far off screen, or invalidate the whole ListView.

My guess is that adding an item is invalidating the ListView.

Your getView method should set the paint flags on the view that it returns. Assuming your list view is displaying a `String[]`, you will also need a `boolean[]` to hold whether or not an item is complete. You would need to initialize this to all falses, add a `completed[i] = !completed[i]` at the beginning of your `onItemClick`. Then you can check `competed[i]` instead of `isStrikeThruText` in your if statement, later in that method. Finally, your getView can look like this

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;
    textView.setText(items[position]);
    if (completed[position]) {
        textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() |  Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    } else {
        textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
    }
    return textView;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, total noob here. Here is my code: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/mpgWZkwU) for the complete mainactivity.java file. i'm learning java as you can see and it's easier for me to learn while making apps. i already made one app so far but i know with this code, i've done something wrong or didn't do something. thanks for your help with this!

Comment: You needed to make an array for storing whether or not an item was completed. I also assumed your list was called "items", but it was actually called "shoppingList", so you needed to change that from my sample code as well. Finally, you needed to override the method in ArrayAdapter, instead of putting it on the main class. [Here](http://0x0.st/skxP.java) is a pastebin of the code after I got it to work on my machine.

Comment: thanks so much for the help and the patience, lol! after looking at the code on your pastebin, i understand what you were saying earlier. it worked!